# Oddball experiment design in E-prime

Tags: cognitive-psychology, measurement, experimental-psychology, emotion

I want to set up an experiment in which there are 3 types of emotional stimuli (A, B, C). A and C would have a 1% recurrence probability, for rare and unexpected stimuli. Is there any sample of [oddball paradigm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oddball_paradigm) for E-Prime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pstnet, the editor of Eprime, does not provide a sample for oddball paradigms. And sharing Eprime scripts is rare but you may find a script of interest here

http://www.nitrc.org/frs/download.php/283/AO_version110804.zip

This is part of an initiative described at http://www.birncommunity.org/resources/tools/fire-primer/multi-site-cognitive-paradigms-for-fmri-studies. File summaries are here http://www.nitrc.org/projects/fbirn (click on "see all files"). This auditory oddball file is far from being a sample though.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this information. I am looking at the file and hopefully I can built up my experiment. However, I cannot run this oddball because it is looking for the scanner.

Comment: There is a place that shares some E-prime scripts: http://step.psy.cmu.edu/scripts/

Comment: Nice - Here is a visual oddball task I programmed with e-prime 1.2 - http://gsite.univ-provence.fr/gsite/Local/lpc/dir/dufau/share/visual_oddball_sample.es

Comment: Thank you so much. I can run it fine. I shall learn from you how to programme my experiment. Probably I have to acknowledge your help, if you provide me with the details. :) Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Not that it answers your specific question, but there is this Inquisit script for auditory oddball: http://millisecond.com/download/library/oddball

There is a 30-day trial version of Inquisit.